# How to configure interval-refresh time in runtime or how to add button in dash which can manually start/pause refresh in Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

```py
import dash
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
global a
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
port=8050
def _create_fig():
    df = pd.read_csv('25nov.csv')
    df.columns=['Sl.no','OffsetRow']
    a = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=df['Sl.no'],y=df['OffsetRow'],)
    return a

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='live-graph',
        animate=True,
        figure=_create_fig()),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='graph-update',
        interval=2*10000,
        n_intervals=0
    ) ]) @app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'))

def refresh_data(n_clicks):
    return _create_fig()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=port)
```

I am using the above code which keeps updating in whatever the interval-time I mentioned but instead of that can we add button that will stop the callback in run time.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:
I think adding a value which will be work in runtime so simply instead of defining
interval component as static that a variable and make it dynamic
Answer 2:
Using client side Callback can do the refresh only when data will be available on request of client